# Eigenvalues of $B$ and $-B$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a real symmetric matrix $B$, if we assume

$QBQ^{T}=-B$

for some orthogonal matrix $Q$, then we know that the eigenvalues of $B$ and $-B$ are the same.

My question is whether matrices of this type have a name in the literature and if they have any special properties.

Thanks!